# Unhandle promise rejection in a basic catch block

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

I'm trying to throw an error from a function to another and to send a res.status(402). I put it in a try-catch block in the most basic way but still got the error.

> : Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing
> inside of an async function without a catch block

this is the calling function:

```js
const validateAction = async (req, res) => {
  const { action, url, mail, orderId } = req.body;
       try {
        requestAction(action, url, mail, orderId);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(402).send({
          status: 402,
          error: "BUG",
        });
      }
```

this is the function I want from where I want to throw the error:

```js
const requestAction = async (action, url, mail, oderId) => {
  const result = actions.find((actionFind) => actionFind.action === action);
  await axios({
    //change the action to "add"
    method: "post",
    url: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    data: {
      key: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      action: "XXXXX",
      service: XXXXXX,
      quantity: XXXXXXXXXX,
    },
  }).then(
    (response) => {
      if (response.data.error) {
        sendLog(
          ` ${response.data.error} --- URL:${url}   ACTION:${action}   QUANTITY:${result.quantity}   ID:${result.id}`,
          "error"
        );
        // here is the throw that's not working---------------------------------------------
        throw response.data.error;
        //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      } else {
        sendMail(mail);
        sendLog(
          ` Succesfully sent it --- URL:${url}   ACTION:${action}   QUANTITY:${result.quantity}   ID:${result.id} To ${mail}`,
          "info"
        );
      }
    },
    (error) => {}
  );
};
```

I believe the answer is not complicated but I don't find it

Comment: `await requestAction(action, url, mail, orderId);`.

Comment: You might want -> `await requestAction(`

Comment: Yea Basic and simple. my bad..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically need to add an

> **await** So  await requestAction(action, url, mail, orderId);

before the request action call.
Thanks to  Felix Kling

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an additional `catch` in the promise chain, for example like this:

```
const validateAction = async (req, res) => {
  const { action, url, mail, orderId } = req.body;
  requestAction(action, url, mail, orderId);
}
   

const requestAction = async (action, url, mail, oderId) => {
  const result = actions.find((actionFind) => actionFind.action === action);
  await axios({
    //change the action to "add"
    method: "post",
    url: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    data: {
      key: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      action: "XXXXX",
      service: XXXXXX,
      quantity: XXXXXXXXXX,
    },
  }).then(
    (response) => {
      if (response.data.error) {
        sendLog(
          ` ${response.data.error} --- URL:${url}   ACTION:${action}   QUANTITY:${result.quantity}   ID:${result.id}`,
          "error"
        );

        throw response.data.error;

      } else {
        sendMail(mail);
        sendLog(
          ` Succesfully sent it --- URL:${url}   ACTION:${action}   QUANTITY:${result.quantity}   ID:${result.id} To ${mail}`,
          "info"
        );
      }
    }).catch(() => {
       console.error(err);
        res.status(402).send({
          status: 402,
          error: "BUG",
        });
   });
};
```